# How to load localstorage with assigned class correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, local-storage

I've been trying to figure out how localstorage works for a few hours, but unfortunately without a positive result. I've created a function in jquery that adds a class in CSS after clicking on the selected selector. I would like to save this result in localstorage, but I don't know how to load it later. Can any of you help me ?

My code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#black-contrast').click(function(){
                $('*').addClass("black-contrast");
                localStorage.setItem('contrast', 'black-contrast');
         });
</script>
```

Comment: localStorage.getItem('contrast')

Answer (score 1):

You can call it from anywhere since it a global object. Well its a property of the window object to be exact.

So whenever you need it just `window.localStorage.getItem(MY_KEY)`